# Debian VM on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

could you help me with an implementation guide for Debian on Azure? I looked in the web but haven't found one.I tried to create a debian virtual machine from the Azure templates but only found images for Ubuntu and Suse

Answer (score 2):

In the new Azure Portal:

New > Compute > See All > Search "Debian" & there are 3 options available.